# Парсинг Telegram каналов с помощью бота

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telebot

Недавно начал разбираться с темой написанием ботов в *Telegram.*
Подскажите, можно ли парсить информацию с других каналов ???
Использую *telebot*

Answer (score 2):

1. bot сам не может добавляться в каналы
2. По-умолчанию, бот может читать из каналов(если он туда добавлен) только команды (сообщения начинающиеся с '/'). Изменить можно через botfuther - /setprivacy

Если добавите бота в чат/канал и измените данную настройку - бот сможет получать сообщения из канала.